# Что это такое и как от этого защищаться?

Tags: взлом, vps

Здравствуйте, имею такую запись от визитера на сайт. У меня VPS, но админ я никакой. Один раз бомбануло мою ось, так что  файл ssh в init.d весил 400 мб и ssh-сервер умер без возможности загрузки. Сносил и ставил все заново. Как бороться с такими записями в поле агента?

```
Время: 9:14
Дата: 25.10.2014
Пользователь: 0 / ip: 208.43.140.35
Ссылка: /index.php
Реферер: () { foo;};echo; /usr/bin/id
Страница: about
Агент: () { foo;};echo;/usr/bin/id
```

Comment: оооо, это относительно свежая уязвимость bash. обновите bash, и все будет в порядке.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-your-server-against-the-shellshock-bash-vulnerability

Comment: bash is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.

Спасибо, но все таки ко мне тогда залезли немного по другому.

Comment: А можно добавить информацию о вашей ОС - вывод команд:

    uname -a
    lsb_release -a

Comment: Linux vps 2.6.32-042stab092.1 #1 SMP Tue Jun 24 09:10:28 MSK 2014 i686 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 (squeeze)
Release: 6.0.6
Codename: squeeze

Comment: О, это ж [Shellshock/Bashdoor](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bashdoor)? Хо, шумиха кончилась, а проблемы нет :)

Answer (score 1):

С учетом того, что поддержка Squeeze закончилась в конце мая 2014 г., возможно, имеет смысл выкачать более новую версию с mirror.yandex.ru (из Wheezy) и накатить?